# Magento 2 - How I can rewrite this file

Tags: magento2, php, module, paypal, paypal-express

I want to change the following file: vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/SmartButtonConfig.php but if I made the modifications directly in the vendor file when I will upgrade my store this modifications will be lost. How I can add this file in the app/code or what is the best way to can modify this file?

Thank you

**Public function:**

```
private function getButtonStyles(string $page): array
{
    $styles = $this->defaultStyles[$page];
    if ((boolean)$this->config->getValue("{$page}_page_button_customize")) {
        $styles['layout'] = $this->config->getValue("{$page}_page_button_layout");
        $styles['size'] = $this->config->getValue("{$page}_page_button_size");
        $styles['color'] = $this->config->getValue("{$page}_page_button_color");
        $styles['shape'] = $this->config->getValue("{$page}_page_button_shape");
        $styles['label'] = $this->config->getValue("{$page}_page_button_label");
        $styles['height'] = 55;
        $styles['tagline'] = false;
        $styles['fundingicons'] = false;
        $styles = $this->updateStyles($styles, $page);
    }
    return $styles;
}
```

I want to add only this:

```
$styles['height'] = 55;
$styles['tagline'] = false;
$styles['fundingicons'] = false;
```

in the  `private function getButtonStyles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create `di.xml` file on following location

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Paypal\Model\SmartButtonConfig" type="Vendor\Extension\Model\SmartButtonConfig" />
</config>
```

2. create `SmartButtonConfig.php` on following location

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Model\SmartButtonConfig.php

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model;

class SmartButtonConfig extends \Magento\Paypal\Model\SmartButtonConfig
{
   //do the code
}
```

Comment: thank you, I have add your code exactly as you say and I see this: Module does not exist

Comment: There was my fault about the module not exist I fix the problem, I edit my post can you check please, because the module is not work and I can't add my code there ... can you give me an example please? Thank you

Comment: Do not modify question completely, ask the seprate questions for another things.

Comment: Hi thank you for your recommandation, but I don't think it is another question, all I just want is too extend that public function, in fact I need to add it in the module that you tell me.